# Accessing a variable value from view in controller - Yii framework

Tags: yii

I had a hidden field in view HTML

```
 <input type="hidden" name="subject_count" id="subject_count" value="1"/>
```

How to get this hidden value in actionCreate method in controller

Answer (score 0):

If your hidden field is part of a form, you may use `$_POST['field_name']` to retrieve it's value after the form is sent to server.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
$subject_count = isset($_POST['subject_count'])? $_POST['subject_count'] : null;
```

$_POST['**subject_count**'] // "subject_count" is the value of **attribute "name"** of hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

$subject_count = $_POST['subject_count'];

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are the general PHP way of doing things, and work if you're using the POST method to submit your form.  If you use GET, you could access the items using the $_GET variable.

To be more Yii-centric, you can use [getQuery()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getQuery-detail) or [getPost()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getPost-detail), which can provide default values for you (and will handle the if-logic that @DanielVaquero had in his answer).

I tend to use [getParam()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail) which will handle post GET and POST data . . .